# docker-compose override not taking additional yml into account?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
```

docker-compose.test.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

`docker-compose config` does **not** show the port. Why?
I'm trying to display the effective compose file, means: the merge result that is also used by `docker-compose up`.

docker-compose version 1.25.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#specifying-multiple-compose-files), docker-compose will only automatically find files named `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml`:

> By default, Compose reads two files, a `docker-compose.yml` and an optional `docker-compose.override.yml` file. By convention, the `docker-compose.yml` contains your base configuration. The override file, as its name implies, can contain configuration overrides for existing services or entirely new services.

If you want to use additional compose files, you need to specify them explicitly using `-f <filename>`:

```
docker-compose up -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml
```

Comment: I can't find any mention of `docker-compose.override.yml` in [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) linked above, however it is documented in the [compose CLI reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#specifying-multiple-compose-files)

Comment: Looks like the docs have changed. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score -2):

By default, docker-compose finds the docker-compose.yml file. The problem you are facing is happening because the port is configured in the other file and DockerCompose doesn't know anything about it. If you want to check the configuration of the other file, you need to pass it as a parameter:

```
docker-compose -f ./path/to/docker-compose.test.yml config
```

Or you can put the port configuration on the first file like this:

```
version: '3.7'
  services:
    db:
      image: mysql:8.0
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
```

And it should work just fine.

Comment: No, docker-compose should automatically detect `docker-compose.<override>.yml` files and merge them. But somehow the override file is not taken into account.

Comment: @membersound you're right. I did not know that. I'm sorry. I notice that in documentation, to override, the file needs to be docker-compose.override.yml. If you rename your second file to the one I just mention it should work just fine.